# Нужно ли преобразовывать в проекте Spring-boot post запрос с данными Json в Gson

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

Нужно ли преобразовывать в проекте Spring-boot post запрос с данными Json в Gson.

UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @PostMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        User user = gson.fromJson(this.json, User.class);
        return "main";
    }
}
```

User

```
public class User {
    private String phone;
    private String message;

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setLastName(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы уже получили объект `User requestUserDetails` в запросе. По этому `User user = ...` уже лишняя операция.Но если очень хочется, то

```java
User user = requestUserDetails
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста. Если происходит вот эта строчка: `@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails` , то это означает, что мы принимаем post запрос и сразу преобразовываем в java объекты? Значит нам тут не нужно использовать Gson, если я использую spring-boot.

Comment: Именно так. В spring-web-mvc так и происходит.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я очень нуждался в Вашем ответе.